# Adding a namespace to asp project whenever you create a new class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I might be lazy about this but what i'm trying to do is add a using statement by default to all my .cs files when I create a new .cs.  This is an asp project and I dont really want to use the web.config.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, I can definitely see the usefulness here.  You might have to create a custom project template in Visual Studio for this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible without messing with VS templates (or T4).

However, if you type out a class name exists or is referenced from the project but that is not currently included by *usings* most versions of VS will give you a little blue dash underneath it when your your mouse is positioned on top of it.  This is a VS context menu and you can activate it by hitting (by default) <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. One of the options in there will be to automatically import the class which will add a using statement.

So not exactly what you want but the process is simply

1. Type the class name you want
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This unfortunately does not currently work with extension methods and you have to use something like Resharper. I handle this (awkwardly) by just typing out the name of the including static extension method class (EnumerableExtensions for the Linq Where for example) and doing the process once for that.

The fact that this is Asp.Net is in this case completely irrelevant and the situation cannot be resolved with a config file. The fix would have to be on the level of C# (so, not happening), or the VS code generator (T4 or custom templates).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an item template that you can use when you add a new cs file to your project instead of adding the regular visual studio template for cs files. Look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx